# Tensorflow: How to train for TF Detect

Tags: tensorflow

The Tensorflow TF Detect for android example draws boxes around humans seen by the camera, however I would like to train a model to detect things other than humans.

How was the example's model trained?

Comment: We're working to expose tools and a walkthrough for retraining the MultiBox detector model; in the meantime you might try the YOLO support also included in the demo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/DetectorActivity.java#L65

The model referenced in the comments will recognize 20 different classes, and you can find walkthroughs for retraining YOLO around the web.

Comment: This is explaining how to train: https://noteoneverything.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-to-train-for-tensorflow-object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have the tools on the TensorFlow repo!

[Supercharge your Computer Vision models with the TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/06/supercharge-your-computer-vision-models.html)